# How can I get the server address in an IIS 7 module OnAuthenticateRequest hook?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, ihttpmodule

Can an IIS 7  module retrieve the server in an OnAuthenticateRequest hook or an OnPostAuthenticateRequest hook?

By "server" I mean the server that the IIS authenticated against (even if it's localhost, for example in the case of windows authentication)

Answer (score 2):

In the method you add as the event delegate, you can do something like:

```
private void onAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var application = (HttpApplication) sender;
  HttpContext context = application.Context;

  string address = context.Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"];
}
```

This will give you IP address of the server currently serving the users request. If you want the servers *name*, then you could use either `SERVER_NAME` or `HTTP_HOST` instead.